# Tomcat8 use the app as ROOT.war

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I was working with Tomcat7 on GoDaddy server, and in order to use my app as the `ROOT` context, I deleted the `ROOT` folder that was there and moved my app which I called it `ROOT.war` and was deployed to `ROOT` folder.

I tried the same approach, now with tomcat8 on Amazon ubuntu server, but it doesn't work.

When I navigate to `myip:8080/` I get error in the javascript console that it's not found and navigating to myip:8080/index.html gives me an empty page.

What is the difference between tomcat8 and tomcat7?

Answer (score 3):

Your app url is:

> host:8443/yourApp/login.html

But you want it in live as

> host:8443/login.html

If this is the case then no need to make it as ROOT.war

you just add some line in conf/server.xml

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Context docBase="usr/apache-tomcat/webapps/YourAppName" path="" reloadable="true" />
</Host>
```

And you just hit

> host:8443

In browser there is..

> host:8443/login.html

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks. will try it. why changing to ROOT wouldn't help?

Comment: also do I need the full docBase?

Comment: as i mention in above server.xml that is unix full path i define in doBase..you just need to update docBase path as per your server ....

Comment: The problem is that only this change creates 2 folders when I transfer myapp .war: ROOT and MYAPP why?

Comment: Basically what happen when you add "docBase" condition[as above i mention ] its just refer to your app folder not ROOT folder and when you hit browser http://hostname then its show landing page from your app ...so ROOT folder is not use ...

Comment: why does it create the ROOT folder? how can I avoid it? I know that I can use rm -rf command, but what for?