# Camel update to 2.17.1 cause 404 on Servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets, apache-camel

I am using Camel with Tomcat and Spring. I was using Camel `2.15.0` and updated to `2.17.1`. I did not make any other changed to my `web.xml` but now the test that I run to hit the endpoint (running in a Tomcat container) is getting a 404. The Tomcat log just shows `"POST / HTTP/1.1" 404`. Is there a difference in how Camel 2.17 deals with the Servlet component?

My web.xml:

```
 <!-- Camel servlet -->
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>http-ingest</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <!-- Camel servlet mapping -->
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>http-ingest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

My RouteBuilder:

```
from("servlet://*?servletName=http=ingest")
      ...
```

***Update***

So I did some regression testing, I compiled an old version of my project which uses camel 2.15.0 and my HTTPS test works fine. Then the ONLY change I made was to update the camel version to 2.17.1, recompiled, deployed and reran the test. With 2.17.1 I get the 404. Again, I made NO OTHER CHANGE besides changing the camel version in my pom.

Comment: negative voter, would you provide a reason?

Comment: This question does not give value to other users, hence a -1. Its basically a rant about upgrade X -> Y and NOT WORK!. You need to investigate much more yourself and look at the server side why it returns a 404.

Comment: @ClausIbsen I disagree, I am asking if anyone knows how the Servlet component of camel changed between versions 1.15 to 1.17 to cause this issue. I have tested it where that is the only change so there must be something in Camel between the versions that has changed the support for this Component.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I spent a bit of time on this and found out there were some commits related to the `CamelHttpTransportServlet` that were different in the `2.15.x` branch and the `2.17.x` branch. These are related to line 44 (see reference 1). It's unfortunate it doesn't appear we can inject a different strategy.
The default strategy appears to support a new REST DSL style define in the new `HttpRestServletResolveConsumerStrategy`.

As I read the `HttpRestServletResolveConsumerStrategy` implementation, I see a few things that may need some further documentation that could be causing the problem. For example, the new strategy expects the return of `request.getPathInfo()` to be non-null (see line 36 of reference 2). Also, this strategy relies in a `RestConsumerContextPathMatcher` (reference 3) that checks for wildcards in the path.

Furthermore, as I look at the documentation and source code, everything (including documentation and code) seems to assume that the servlet is deployed as a war that is not the root in the app server. I don't think this would be a big deal, but I'm wondering how your server.xml configuration is setup to map your war in case you are deploying to root.

Definetely looks like an obscure issue. :)

I hope these helps!

References:

1. https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-servlet/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/servlet/CamelHttpTransportServlet.java
2. https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/555627d49e48df00f325ec05f382b79415cadffc/components/camel-http-common/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/http/common/HttpRestServletResolveConsumerStrategy.java
3. https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/a90d28d1c48594bf3f1765a5dbe34c07f99a9960
4. [Tomcat8 use the app as ROOT.war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970008/tomcat8-use-the-app-as-root-war)